# Wintersmith serve /manifest.json

Tags: pug, wintersmith

I'm trying to serve a /manfest.json file - it has some icon information for android.

```
  {
    "name": "woot.io",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "\/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image\/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "\/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image\/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#0d87e9",
    "display": "standalone"
  }
```

When I put the file in /contents, Wintersmith renders it to /manifest.html.  No good.

With this in /contents/manifest.json:

```
{
  "template": "manifest.jade",
  "filename": "manifest.json"
}
```

Uses a template, but I haven't found syntax to get Jade to output json.  Is there a better way?  I feel like I'm missing something easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a [`wintersmith-asis`](https://github.com/luckyrandom/wintersmith-asis) plugin which makes this a little simpler. Just install the plugin, add it to your plugins config and then rename `manifest.json` to `_asis_.manifest.json`

https://github.com/luckyrandom/wintersmith-asis

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution:

content/manifest.md

```
---
template: manifest.jade
filename: manifest.json
---
```

templates/manifest.jade

```
|{
|   "name": "woot.io",
|   "icons": [
|       {
|           "src": "\/android-chrome-192x192.png",
|           "sizes": "192x192",
|           "type": "image\/png"
|       },
|       {
|           "src": "\/android-chrome-512x512.png",
|           "sizes": "512x512",
|           "type": "image\/png"
|       }
|   ],
|   "theme_color": "#0d87e9",
|   "display": "standalone"
|}
```